# Object attributes to JavaScript-like hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

`This is kind of an odd question, but I don't .......`

I overcomplicated the original question. If you want to see the original question, look through the previous edits. Here's my revised question by combining my two previous questions, as simple as I can explain it:

I have an object. The object can have (x) amount of fields and all of the fields and values can be different. Example:

`#<User name="John", height=75>` or `#<Comment title="First!">`

I'm using a gem/db requires a specific format for queries. This is the format that the query MUST have: `CREATE (u:User{attribute: "Some att.", another_att: 32})` and so on and so forth. Notice the JavaScript-like hash it uses for its values.

I'm trying to interpolate an object's attributes into the query. But I don't know how to map the correct fields and values into the query. Here's an example of what I start with and what I want to end with:

`object = #<User name="John", height=75>` =>

`"CREATE (u:User{name: "John", height: 75})"`

What's the simplest way to achieve this? Thanks to everyone who's helped so far.

Note that it is possible to convert the attributes to a Ruby hash: `{:name => "John", :height => 75}`, (as explained in the original question) but it was too confusing to change that hash to the syntax in the query, so I've backtracked and simplified my question.

Comment: It sounds like the gem you are describing does not want queries in JSON style hashes, but rather as JSON itself. Just `to_json` the hash and it will likely work.

Comment: The only problem with that is that `.to_json` turns the hash into `"name" : "John"`, but the query API isn't looking for `"name"`, it's looking for `name:`. Here's the error when I use JSON: `SyntaxError: unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input`

Comment: @muistooshort Changed it to 'Javascript'. Thanks.

Comment: The actual query is the Neo4j Cypher query API. The gem is Neography. I just want to be able to translate an object into a 'Javascript' style hash where I could directly interpolate it into the query. Here's the actual query: `"CREATE (u:User#{hash})"` and when `hash= {attributes: 'some attribute'}` is inserted manually, it runs. There's got to be a way to parse out the correct information and either insert it into a Javascript style hash or hardcode the information with colons into a fake hash/string that then gets interpolated. Yeah, I dumbed down the query for the SO question w/ same basics

Comment: And Neography wants the query as a string that looks like a JavaScript object literal?

Comment: @user3181113 Cypher isn't Ruby. As such, they don't expect literal new-style ruby hashes but Cypher collections which just happen to look similar. That said, it would surprise me if the gem would require you to construct these by hand using string concatenation. I'd rather expect that you could just pass a hash and have the gem generate the correct expressions.

Comment: @HolgerJust Didn't say Cypher was Ruby. I wondered if there was a way to use Ruby to create hash that would match Cypher.

Comment: @muistooshort Here is one style using hash rocket vs non hash rocket:`[6] pry(main)> @neo.execute_query("CREATE (u:User{name: 'John'})")
=> {"columns"=>[], "data"=>[]}
        [7] pry(main)> @neo.execute_query("CREATE (u:User{:name => 'John'})")
Neography::SyntaxException: Invalid input ':': expected whitespace, an identifier, '}' or UnsignedInteger (line 1, column 16)
"CREATE (u:User{:name => 'John'})"`    The first style works, the second doesn't.

Comment: @muistooshort And here's using a variable `hash = {name: 'John'}` and interpolating it into the query. It evals it exactly the same as the second query above: `[10] pry(main)> @neo.execute_query("CREATE (u:User#{hash})")
Neography::SyntaxException: Invalid input ':': expected whitespace, an identifier, '}' or UnsignedInteger (line 1, column 16)
"CREATE (u:User{:name=>"John"})"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by going through the Ruby docs. It was way simpler than it seemed. The `.collect` method (or map) can be used to map each value and field to an interpolated string that can be put into a query. Example:

```
hash = {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith'}
hash.collect {|k, v| "#{k}: #{v}"}

=> ["first_name: John", "last_name: Smith"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that the literal is the problem. The JSON-style syntax
was introduced in Ruby 1.9 as a literal abbreviation for the longer
"hashrocket" style.

```
> {name: 'John'} == {:name => 'John'}
=> true
```

Comment: `Invalid input ':': expected whitespace, an identifier, '}' or UnsignedInteger` Nope. That's the problem because the JSON style hash isn't Ruby, it's part of the query language. When the hash is evaluated, the output is with a hash rocket. Type `{name: 'John'}` into irb. It will evaluate it as `{:name => 'John'}`.

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: MRI 2.1. It's not the version of Ruby that's the problem. Ruby is acting how it's supposed to. I just need to find a way to stringify a hash without it being evaluated beforehand. Because when it's evaluated, it becomes a hash rocket hash.

Comment: Tried that. Comments under original post ^.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't make sense. There has to be something else going on here.

A hash is a hash is a hash, it doesn't matter what syntax you used to create it, it's still the *exact* same hash. Those four are 100% equivalent (and if they aren't, that's a bug in your Ruby implementation):

```
hash = { name: 'John' }

hash = { :name => 'John' }

hash = {}
hash[:name] = 'John'

hash = Hash.new
hash[%Q|name|.to_sym] = %w@John@.first
```

There is absolutely no difference between them. There is no such thing as a "Hashrocket `Hash`" or "JSON-style `Hash`". There *is* a difference between the literals used to construct those hashes, but that difference only exists at parse time. At runtime, they are just as identical as `16`, `0x10` and `020` are.